# Recover Redmine Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, backup, postgresql, redmine

I am getting crazy with something and I would like some help if there is someone can help.

I had an Ubuntu Server where I was running the Redmine Project Management application; and some days ago the Server crashed.
I have a backup of the application files (it was in `/usr/share/redmine`) and a backup of the PostgreSQL Database (named redmine). But I did not did the installation of that Server and the Redmine inside it, so I have limited information about which versions were inside and how was it configured.

In another Server: **Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS**, with **Apache2** and **PostgreSQL 9.1**, I have recovered the folder content in `/usr/share/redmine` and recovered the redmine database in a PostgreSQL. But I can't not find anywhere, in the folder files or database, **which redmine version it was**; and as I have read I need to know the version **to know which Ruby, Rails, RubyGems corresponding versions I have to install** in the Server.

Somebody knows what can I do, or where can I find the information to reinstall the environment so the Redmine can continue working?

Thank you very very much.

P.D.: in the path `/usr/share/redmine/config` ther isn't any `database.yml` file to know the old environment.

Comment: I can only guess, but `/usr/share/redmine` might only have the common files for the redmine installation. Do you have backups of any other files? Configuration might have been in e.g. `/etc/redmime`.

Answer (score 1):

[The folks over on Super User have answered this question](https://superuser.com/a/113976/26231) -- in your redmine install directory (probably `/usr/share/redmine`) there is a `CHANGELOG` file -- the version number installed should be the most recent one in that file.

If that fails, you can always [upgrade your redmine installation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade) -- meet all the requirements for the latest version and then proceed per those instructions, and redmine should make itself Just Work. This is of course predicated on your ability to upgrade without breaking anything your environment depends on...